# How to stop loading description with hover effect in homepage in blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP7ej.png) is my problem and This is my [blog](http://www.w0ndersoftheworld.blogspot.com)..

I also tried locked my description in homepage by removing `<data:post.body/>`

But the description is hided but hover on effect is still continues i dont know why this problem has found and i have found java script code in my template like the above. or should i have any alternative code? Iam using blogger platform.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
/* -------------------------------------*/
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('z U(e,l){G(e["\\6\\5\\d\\3\\v\\A\\u"]("\\r")!=-1){j s=e["\\c\\y\\9\\6\\4"]("\\r");10(j i=0;i<s["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"];i++){G(s[i]["\\6\\5\\d\\3\\v\\A\\u"]("\\o")!=-1){s[i]=s[i]["\\c\\R\\w\\c\\4\\a\\6\\5\\7"](s[i]["\\6\\5\\d\\3\\v\\A\\u"]("\\o")+1,s[i]["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"])}};e=s["\\11\\m\\6\\5"]("")};l=(l<e["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"]-1)?l:e["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"]-2;Z(e["\\k\\8\\f\\a\\Y\\4"](l-1)!="\\q"&&e["\\6\\5\\d\\3\\v\\A\\u"]("\\q",l)!=-1){l++};e=e["\\c\\R\\w\\c\\4\\a\\6\\5\\7"](0,l-1);13 e+"\\n\\n\\n"};z 19(B){j t=J["\\7\\3\\4\\I\\9\\3\\b\\3\\5\\4\\F\\E\\T\\d"](B);j S=18;j D="\\r\\d\\6\\M\\o"+U(t["\\6\\5\\5\\3\\a\\O\\C\\N\\Q"],S)+"\\r\\h\\d\\6\\M\\o";t["\\6\\5\\5\\3\\a\\O\\C\\N\\Q"]=D};z 17(B){j t=J["\\7\\3\\4\\I\\9\\3\\b\\3\\5\\4\\F\\E\\T\\d"](B);j P="";j H=t["\\7\\3\\4\\I\\9\\3\\b\\3\\5\\4\\c\\F\\E\\C\\f\\7\\12\\f\\b\\3"]("\\6\\b\\7");G(H["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"]>=1){P="\\r\\6\\b\\7\\q\\k\\9\\f\\c\\c\\x\\g\\w\\f\\9\\c\\f\\b\\g\\q\\c\\a\\k\\x\\g"+H[0]["\\c\\a\\k"]+"\\g\\q\\p\\6\\d\\4\\8\\x\\g"+16+"\\y\\v\\g\\q\\8\\3\\6\\7\\8\\4\\x\\g"+X+"\\y\\v\\g\\h\\o"};j D=P;t["\\6\\5\\5\\3\\a\\O\\C\\N\\Q"]=D};$(J)["\\a\\3\\f\\d\\E"](z(){$("\\V\\k\\a\\3\\d\\6\\4")["\\8\\4\\b\\9"]("\\r\\f\\q\\8\\a\\3\\u\\x\\g\\8\\4\\4\\y\\L\\h\\h\\p\\p\\p\\n\\w\\9\\m\\7\\7\\3\\a\\4\\8\\3\\b\\3\\K\\n\\k\\m\\b\\h\\g\\o\\F\\9\\m\\7\\7\\3\\a\\4\\8\\3\\b\\3\\K\\r\\h\\f\\o");15(z(){G(!$("\\V\\k\\a\\3\\d\\6\\4\\L\\M\\6\\c\\6\\w\\9\\3")["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"]){14["\\9\\m\\k\\f\\4\\6\\m\\5"]["\\8\\a\\3\\u"]="\\8\\4\\4\\y\\L\\h\\h\\p\\p\\p\\n\\w\\9\\m\\7\\7\\3\\a\\4\\8\\3\\b\\3\\K\\n\\k\\m\\b\\h"}},W)});',62,72,'|||x65|x74|x6E|x69|x67|x68|x6C|x72|x6D|x73|x64|strx|x61|x22|x2F||var|x63|chop|x6F|x2E|x3E|x77|x20|x3C||div|x66|x78|x62|x3D|x70|function|x4F|pID|x54|summary|x79|x42|if|img|x45|document|x39|x3A|x76|x4D|x48|imgtag|x4C|x75|summ|x49|removeHtmlTag|x23|3000|img_thumb_height|x41|while|for|x6A|x4E|return|window|setInterval|img_thumb_width|createSummaryAndThumb2|summary_noimg|createSummaryAndThumb'.split('|'),0,{}))//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show all relevant code in a non compressed format? There's no way anyone is going to debug that :)

Comment: This is my full template code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8uxlaT0y4jtZkJmZ1JzcDlIT2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please copy the relevant bits into the question?